# Push an entirely new project on an existing GIT repo

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am not sure, if this is a stupid question. But I have git repo for a project. When recently I found that the code has become extremely messy, I created a new project (locally) and rewrote the whole application. Now, if I push this new code, into the existing repo, will there be any artifacts, or will it be clean?

Comment: I think it should be clean. You can't do this without using the force option, i.e. `git push -f`. Obviously this will destroy whatever you had there before, so you might want to clone the old repo somewhere just in case you ever want anything from it.

Comment: You could push the new code to a new branch.

Answer (score 0):

If by "created a new project", you mean you just rm -rf'ed all your code (except your .git subdir) and started from scratch, well all your old commits are still in the history and you can get all of them back (if not, it wouldn't be a very good SCM tool). So, if these are artifacts, then yes, they will all be there. If you forgot to delete a dot prefix file and don't normally see that and checked all your new stuff in, your old dot prefix file would still be there with your new stuff.

If instead you mean you created a new git repo and did a "git add remote remoteURL" and then did a "git push --force" then you would force your new master onto the origin, so could lose your data in the origin. OTOH, the objects dir in the origin will still have the old blobs for some time until they probably get garbage collected as they will now be dangling.